# Android Native script Build error with Unable to apply changes on device: emulator-5554. Error is: Invalid Version: null

Tags: javascript, android, angular, nativescript, hybrid-mobile-app

0

I have Hybrid App with Nativescript, and upgraded the Angular version from 14 to 16.2 when I take Android  build i am getting this bellow error. When I try run the build i am getting below message

```
`Project successfully built.
Build time: 21.834 s.
The build result is located at: /Users/gayathri/Projects/abc/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
Installing on device emulator-5554...
Successfully installed on device with identifier 'emulator-5554'.
Unable to apply changes on device: emulator-5554. Error is: Invalid Version: null.`
```

any My package.json is

```
{
  "name": "nativescriptabc",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nx serve",
    "build": "nx build",
    "test": "nx test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "16.2.2",
    "@angular/common": "16.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "16.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "16.2.2",
    "@angular/forms": "16.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "16.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "16.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "16.2.2",
    "@nativescript/angular": "^16.0.0",
    "@nativescript/core": "~8.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "~14.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "~7.0.0",
    "@nota/nativescript-webview-ext": "^8.0.2",
    "@nx/angular": "14.3.6",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "nativescript-insomnia": "^2.0.0",
    "nativescript-ngx-fonticon": "~7.0.0",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "^1.0.4",
    "rxjs": "^7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "0.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "16.2.0",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "16.2.0",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "16.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "16.0.3",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "16.0.3",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "16.0.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~16.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "16.2.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "16.2.2",
    "@nativescript/android": "8.3.1",
    "@nativescript/ios": "8.4.1",
    "@nativescript/eslint-plugin": "~0.0.4",
    "@nativescript/nx": "^4.0.1",
    "@nativescript/types": "~8.2.0",
    "@nativescript/webpack": "~5.0.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^16.2.0",
    "@nstudio/angular": "14.3.0",
    "@nstudio/nativescript": "14.3.0",
    "@nstudio/nativescript-angular": "14.3.0",
    "@nstudio/web": "14.3.0",
    "@nstudio/web-angular": "14.3.0",
    "@nx/angular": "16.7.4",
    "@nx/cypress": "16.7.4",
    "@nx/eslint-plugin": "16.7.4",
    "@nx/jest": "16.7.4",
    "@nx/js": "16.7.4",
    "@nx/linter": "16.7.4",
    "@nx/workspace": "16.7.4",
    "@schematics/angular": "16.2.0",
    "@types/jest": "29.4.4",
    "@types/node": "16.11.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.62.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.62.0",
    "cypress": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint": "8.46.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "2.14.0",
    "jasmine-marbles": "~0.9.2",
    "ng-packagr": "16.2.1",
    "nx": "16.7.4",
    "nx-cloud": "16.3.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.5",
    "postcss-import": "~14.1.0",
    "postcss-preset-env": "~7.5.0",
    "postcss-url": "~10.1.3",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "sass": "^1.30.0",
    "ts-jest": "29.1.1",
    "ts-node": "10.9.1",
    "typescript": "5.1.6"
  },
  "nativescript-nx": {
    "prefix": "nativescriptabc",
    "framework": "angular"
  }
}
```

Configures the current project to target the selected platform. When you add a target platform, the NativeScript CLI creates a corresponding platform-specific subdirectory under the platforms directory. This platform-specific directory contains the necessary files to let you build your project for the target platform.